# Import tumblr post to wordpress blog

Tags: plugins, import, api, tumblr

When I add a new post in my tumblr account, automatically that post of tumblr would be sync with my wordpress account. Its not necessary that at sync time I have to be logged in wordpress. In simple words, tumblr post will be automatically shown to wordpress blog. I donot know how it will work. If any body have any plugin or api which match to my requirement. I will very much thankful.

i am using this plugin :- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tumblr-importer/

But problem is that i have to import every time post is added in tumblr.Hope that makes sense. Its really annoying for me. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Iframe/embeded your tumblr into your wordpress new-page!? might not be the best but it will work...

wordpress new page

```
header

tumblr tempalte code
or iframe

footer
```

lets wait a bit for some more contributions...someone might have a better way to do it. You can edit this answer to improve it.

Comment: jose, are you making your Answers [Community Wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/185667) on purpose?

Comment: isnt that the only way to everyone edit and improve it? or i misunderstood the wiki concept? if yes, yes. ty..ok. i´ll read it better...sry.. EDITED: ok... sry. Misunderstood the wiki post. Though it was the only way for everyone edit my own answers... now i got it. And yea..none so far were for the Community Wiki.